# Can I add a hyperlink using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hyperlink using pure CSS. (I can't add an `<a>` tag in the HTML.) In my code below, I'd like to add a link around the image with just CSS. Is that possible?

**HTML**

```
<div class="target">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.target img {
  cursor: pointer;
  content: "href(http://www.w3schools.com)"
  /*content: "url(http://www.w3schools.com)"*/
}
```

Comment: No, use JavaScript if you don't wants to define it in `HTML`.

Comment: No, even better, use....HMTL:-)

Comment: Why don't you use HTML?, Css stands for Styling not behaving...

Comment: Because of my work does not allow html editor : (

Answer (score 0):

You can you with a small script line -

```html
<div class="target" onclick="window.location.href='http://w3schools.com'">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

But without `a` and pure css not possible.